# Present perfect/past simple

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> A: My computer broke, ever since that happened I've been trying to fix it but everything I have tried hasn't worked. I tried calling my brother who is an expert but nothing, I tried many times leaving it to cool off but it didn't work, what can I do?
>
> B: Have you tried opening it maybe there's something wrong inside.
>
> A: **I have tried many times already / I tried many times / I have tried many times/ I tried many times** already but it didn't work.

Now the problem is that since I have already listed  all the things that  I have tried in past simple if this other one is part of the things tried can it be in present perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the focus is on whether you did it as of the moment of being asked, perfect certainly works, especially since the question is asked in perfect. Note that "I have" rather than "I've" comes across as a bit formal. And "several" feels more idiomatic to me than "many". Also, "already" works better with perfect than simple.

Comment: So even if I don't use "already" present perfect would be ok anyway?